# Confused about the ground rules of sequent calculus (LK): cut or no cut?

Tags: sequent-calculus

There are many books and internet tutorials about sequent calculus for classical first-order logic (LK – which, if I understood correctly, is the one that allows for any number of formulae on the right side). I am actually only concerned with propositional logic.

Some web pages list the ground rules including the cut rule; an example is Toman's [lecture notes](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Edavid/cs848/sequent-calc.pdf). Others exclude the cut rule; an example is Slaney's [Logic Notes](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ejks/LogicNotes/rules-sequent.html). The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) itself makes one list with, and another without: compare [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Reduction_trees) with [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Inference_rules).

Is it because of the cut-elimination theorem that some tutorials don't list the cut rule? But I have also read (eg [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem#Consequences_of_the_theorem) again) that without the cut rule some proofs would be unfeasibly long.

I would be thankful if you could explain me where these differences in presentation come from.

Comment: That’s right: start with Cut and then prove Cut-elimination. See textbookse.g. G.Takeuti, Proof Theory (1975)